# How to fix this loop for sorting packages by weight

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I need to create a program that asks the customer how many packages they have (after the input it creates an array of that size) which then ask the customer to enter the weights of them. It then has to sort the packages into small, medium, or large and then prints how many of each size package there is.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int small = 0;
    int medium = 0;
    int large = 0;
    int size = 0;
    int[] intArray = {size}; 


    System.out.printf("Please enter the number of weights to enter: ");
    size = scan.nextInt();



    for (double i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++){
        if (i < size)
            System.out.print("Please Enter weight1: ");
            double weights = scan.nextInt();




    System.out.println("\nPackage Weights");
        System.out.print(weights);



        if (weights <= 5)
            small = 1 + small;
        if (weights <= 10 && weights >= 6)
            medium = 1 + medium;
        if (weights >= 11)
            large = 1 + large;

            System.out.println("\n\nSmall: " + small);
            System.out.println("Medium: " +  medium);
            System.out.println("Large:" + large);

    }
}
```

}

I got the sorting to work, but I can only get it to ask for one package, which means my array and loop aren't working. Just now learning arrays / loops so i'm kinda stuck on this.

Comment: Re-do your indentation and check your brackets.

Comment: please format your code, just from looking over it i might suspect you´re missing some curly brackets here.

Answer (score 2):

It only asks for one package because you initialize `intArray` as an array containing exactly one element.  Instead of pointlessly initializing it in its declaration, before you even know how large it needs to be, create and assign the needed array after you input its length. At your option, you can move the whole declaration there:

```
    // ...
    size = scan.nextInt();
    int[] intArray = new int[size];
```

Inasmuch as that's the case, I'm inclined to doubt your claim that you had the sorting part working -- you don't have a suitable place to store the weights that are entered.  Perhaps you cut that part out of the code you presented.  Indeed, if your program ever had any semblance of sorting then you must have performed quite a hack job on it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the time at which your intArray is initialised.
It gets initialised just after size is initialized with the value of 0.
Therefore you end up with a single Element in your array.

All you have to do is move the initialisation of your intArray after the user  input:

```
int[] intArray; 


    System.out.printf("Please enter the number of weights to enter: ");
    size = scan.nextInt();
    intArray = new int[size]; //<-- initialization of the array after the user input 


    for (double i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++){
```